# Show an error message in an LWC in a Flow using standard components

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, toast

I have a custom Lightning Web Component that I am using in a Flow. Unfortunately, the standard `ShowToastEvent` event does not work when an LWC is in a Flow.

Is there an alternative component I can use for this? Not necessarily a toast message, but something I can use without creating a separate component.

Something like on the standard detail page perhaps?

[image]

This is my component, and I want to handle any errors from the delete button.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-form
        record-id={recordId}
        object-api-name={objectApiName}
        layout-type="Full"
        mode="view"
    ></lightning-record-form>
    <template if:true={showDeleteButton}>
        <lightning-button variant="destructive" label="Delete" icon-name="utility:delete" onclick={handleDelete}></lightning-button>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: We addressed this by displaying the error in the custom LWC's rendering.

Comment: Could you share a sample of the code? On discussing with some colleagues I've gone with some text formatted with `slds-text-color_error` but it doesn't look that great as it's just the text.

Comment: We didn't try to use SLDS error colouring. Instead there are options like showing a warning [utility icon](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#utility) and the error message in a div with `.slds-theme_error` [theme](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/themes/), or presentation of the error in an [alert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-alert/documentation). Other options are available.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW that's helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than using a customization such as [unofficialsf.com's Show Toast Flow Action](https://unofficialsf.com/show-toast-flow-action/), I don't know of any standard way to address this issue. There are, however, many ways you could deal with errors, inline within your own LWC components.

An example might be to use something like this in your component, showing this part of the template when there's an error (which would typically actually originate from a property of your LWC):

```
<div class="slds-theme_error">
    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:error" variant="inverse" size="small"></lightning-icon>
    <span class="slds-p-left_xx-small">Some error message</span>
</div>
```

This might look something like:

[image: Simple error message display]

Alternatively, you might like to use the `lightning-alert` [component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-alert/documentation) to present the message in a dismissable "dialog".

There are many other options you could choose from, including simply showing the errors in [toasts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation) (though as you said these may not work in all contexts).