# ShowToastEvent does not fire from LWC placed on Screen Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow, toast

I have implemented this example provided here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/385665/138510  provided by @vitalii-dehnerys

But still, the Toast does not get fired from the LWC when it sits on a screen flow.

Does anyone else have this problem now too, OR do you have a work around?

Comment: Are you testing this in debug mode or in the actual Lightning Experience?

Comment: Initially, yes, I was using the "Run" button in the flow designer.   I also tried running the test flow from a URL   ( /flow/my_flow  ).    In these cases, it did not work.   But see below -- it DOES work when the flow is launched from an Action Button that specifically calls a named flow (not a URL button.)

Comment: note [UnofficialSf.com show toast component](https://unofficialsf.com/show-toast-flow-action/) in case you don't want to maintain your own lwc

Answer (score 3):

The `ShowToastEvent` event does not work when the component is used in a Flow launched by a URL button.

If you really need a toast, you can make your own component: https://salesforcecodex.com/salesforce/custom-toast-with-custom-duration-in-lwc/

If you're using them for errors, there are some other options that aren't toasts: [Show an error message in an LWC in a Flow using standard components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/408726/show-an-error-message-in-an-lwc-in-a-flow-using-standard-components)

Comment: Actually, with more thorough testing, I can say that ShowToastEvent  DOES work in a flow, as long as the flow is launched via an Action Button -- for example on a record page, as in the example.    Where it does **not** work is when the flow is launched with a URL button, like what you might use on a listview  (this is where I was using it.)   So .... mixed results.

Answer (score 0):

I asked in a comment before if you ran it with debug mode because of this: It works when it runs in a Lightning Experience UI. **In debug mode and when run directly from the URL it doesn't work because it doesn't have the Lightning runtime available to handle the event** and thus show the toast.

If you want to test your flow and see the toast, unfortunately you'll have to have an active version and run it on a Lightning Experience page.

Comment: Thanks @renato.   In my case the flow is not launched in a traditional way -- it's launched  by URL, which I think causes it to run inside of an Aura container.   Something about how this flow is launched prevents the Toast from displaying.   I've worked around it by popping alert boxes.   I may go back and roll a toast-like component as others were suggested, but for now I'm good.